# join and aggregate using django orm

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I have two tables 
user and purchase

purchase table has columns
user purchase_total

and user table has columns
userid and username

In here i want to do inner join to find the total purchase for each user

I need to how do I do the inner join between user and purchase and aggregate to find the total purchase for each given user. using django ORM Query

below is the query i have that would do this type of join:

select user.* sum(purchase_total) AS total purchase from user inner join purchase on purchase.id = user.id

How do I create a django orm query using this.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your Purchase Model has relation like this:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    user = models.ForiegnKey(User, related_name='purchases')
```

Then you can do the join and aggregation like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

User.objects.annotate(total_purchase=Sum('purchases'))
```

For more information, you can check this [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards).